# Asp.net - button doesnt work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working wiht OutBrain API and i am trying to get some data from the server.

I made a simple HTML page that just take marketer ID and return his name.

When i click the button- nothing happen. Can someone tell me what my problem is ?

I am using visual studio 2013 and working with MVC ASP.NET.

Thanks !

Code :

index.cshtml

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<br />
<div class="details">
    <label>Enter Marketer ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="marketerID">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="buttonB">OK</button>
    <section class="details">
        <div class="name">
            <label>Name</label>
            <label id="nameMarketer"></label>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/outBrain.js"></script>
```

outBrain.js

```
$("#buttonB").on('click', function () {

function getMarketer ()
{
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/home/GetOutBrainMarketers",
            data: { id: $("marketerID").val() },
            success: function (result) {
                var marketer = JSON.parse(result);
                document.getElementById("nameMarketer").innerHTML = (marketer.name);
            }
        }
        )
   }
});
```

HomeController.cs

```
namespace OutBrain_test.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public async Task<string> GetOutBrainMarketers(string ID)
    {
        var baseAddress = new Uri("https://api.outbrain.com/amplify/v0.1/marketers/" + ID);

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
        {

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("OB-TOKEN-V1", AuthorizeOutBrain().Result);

            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("marketers/"+ ID))
            {

                string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return responseData;
            }

        }

    }

    public async Task<string> AuthorizeOutBrain()
    {

        var baseAddress = new Uri("https://api.outbrain.com/amplify/v0.1/login");

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
        {

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("authorization", "BASIC BASE-64-ENC(my-username:my-pass)");

            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("login"))
            {

                string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return responseData;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you wrap `$.ajax` by `getMarketer` function? What does it mean?

Comment: ok, ok maybe thats my problem, but thats it ?

Comment: Try to unwrap it and click again.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, try to press F12, click on `Network` tab. Then, clicking on the button again to check what's happen. If there was nothing in there (`Network` tab). Try to insert a line `console.log('hit...')` inside your js function to check again, open `Console` tab to check. If still nothing, checking for reference to the js.

Comment: @TânNguyễn, all browsers today have this F12 tool, not just Chrome.

Comment: @TsahiAsher Not at all, in Firefox, if you have installed Firebug before, by pressing F12, it would open Firebug tool, not Developer tool.

Comment: If you return `Task<JsonResult>` and not `Task<string>`, it will save you parsing the string as JSON on the client, because jQuery would already do it for you and give you an object at `result`. Also, if you're using jQuery, you can write `$("#nameMarketer").text(marketer.name);` instead of `document.getElementById("nameMarketer").innerHTML = (marketer.name);` which will also do HTML encoding for you.

Comment: It doesn't matter, @TânNguyễn. You still get a developer tool with network monitoring, whether it be Firebug or the native one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used button html control replace it with following

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="OK" id="buttonB" />
```

make following changes in outBrain.js file

```
function pageLoad()
{
    $("#buttonB").on('click', function () {
              getMarketer();
    });
}

function getMarketer()
{
$.ajax({
        url: "/home/GetOutBrainMarketers",
        data: "{ id:'" + $("marketerID").val() +"'}",
        success: function (result) {
            var marketer = JSON.parse(result);
            document.getElementById("nameMarketer").innerHTML = (marketer.name);
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Why? You can register a click handler on a button element as well. It doesn't need to be an input element.

Comment: I think the button control might be post back on onclick event,but this behavior is with the input type="submit" button,my confusion sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Your button JavaScript click handler doesn't do anything except for defining a function. You need to do this:

```
$("#buttonB").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({            {
            url: "/home/GetOutBrainMarketers",
            data: { id: $("marketerID").val() },
            success: function (result) {
                var marketer = JSON.parse(result);
                document.getElementById("nameMarketer").innerHTML = (marketer.name);
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

case sensitive problem . home controller api parameter name is "ID"  and your ajax calling  you give "id" in small case please change it in uppercase and try

```
 $(function () 
   {
$("#buttonB").click(function () {
    $.ajax({  
        url: "/home/GetOutBrainMarketers",
        data: { ID: $("marketerID").val() },
        success: function (result) {
            var marketer = JSON.parse(result);
            document.getElementById("nameMarketer").innerHTML =       (marketer.name);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: its doesnt work its give me this problem : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at http://localhost:-----/Scripts/outBrain.js:1:1

Comment: i dodnt undersatnd , i add the <script src="~/Scripts/outBrain.js"></script> to the view file. can u be more specific ?

Comment: @Tal Try to add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` before `<script src="~/Scripts/outBrain.js"></script>`.

Comment: @Tal you need to jquery reference if you use any jquery function .